# Getting 32-bit application to use more than 2GB on 64-bit Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, memory, 32-bit

I'm trying to get a 32-bit app to be able to use more than 2GB on my 64-bit edition of Windows 7 Ultimate. Currently, it crashes when it hits 2GB. I've heard there're ways to move this up to 3GB in 32-bit editions of Windows XP, Vista, and 7. Setting increaseuserva doesn't seem to work. (I have 4GB installed. If you're wondering, it's Dwarf Fortress.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778.aspx#memory_limits) the maximum address space for a 32-bit process is 4Gb on 64bit Windows 7. **But**, this requires the process to have the `IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE` flag set.

Setting `IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE` is more of a problem, as it has to be done at the *linking* stage when compiling the software. See [another MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz223b1z.aspx) for a bit more info.

You might also wish to see [this StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740308/why-2-gb-memory-limit-when-running-in-64-bit-windows) question, and maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570589/can-a-32bit-process-access-more-memory-on-a-64bit-windows-os) one as well, which provide some general info.

Comment: The LAA flag can be set on an exe after the link. However if the exe assumes that user mode addresses will never be larger than 0x7FFFFFFF it will crash.